# Which of the following equations has the greatest number of real solutions?(math subject GRE exam 1268 Q.17)

Tags: polynomials

Could anyone give me a hint for the most rapid way for solving this question (solving it in exactly 2.5 minutes)?
Thanks!

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt this is really doable in 2'30" (unless you are already in full concentration mode).

You spot at once that D has no solution (knowing that $e^x>x$) and C (first degree) has one. Rewrite E as $\cos x=e^{x^2}\ge1$ and it has exactly one solution ($x=0$).

B is quadratic and potentially has two solutions. By checking the discriminant, $76$, it indeed has them.

A is cubic and potentially has three roots. But the derivative $3x^2+1$ is positive so that there are no extrema and a single root.

Comment: This is a math subject GRE exam question, this is why it has to be solved in this time.

Comment: For (A), think of the intersection between the curve $y=x^3$ and the line $y=10-x$, and it's immediate that there's only one real solution.

Comment: @HansLundmark: how is it immediate ?

Comment: $x \mapsto x^3$ is a strictly increasing continuous function which takes on all real values, $x \mapsto 10-x$ is a strictly decreasing continuous function which takes on all real values.

Comment: @HansLundmark: so what's the difference with taking the derivative and showing it positive ?

Comment: Not much, except that if you're in a hurry, you might want to use that you already *know* these facts about (the graphs of) $x^3$ and $10-x$. (It wasn't meant as a criticism of your answer, which I upvoted already yesterday.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried in 2.5. minutes, so more a guess than anything else really, for somebody of my limited skills.

So, $E$ has one real solution for $x=0$, as the Gaussian is bounded above by $1$ and the secant is bounded below by the same value, a graphical approach more than rigorous.

$A$ also has one real solution due to, I hope, a quick derivative check.

Same for $C$ and $D$ (due to linearity and and easy exponential inequality respectively).

My best guess is then $B$, which I verified it has two by checking the discriminant.